# Laravel 4: Post to a Controller function and Redirect to a Resource Controller get 200 but nothing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to support two different api route at the same time, so I direct one to another.

my `route.php`:

```
Route::controller('auth', 'AuthController');
Route::resource(  'user', 'UserController');
```

my `AuthController.php`:

```
public function postSignup()
{
    return Redirect::route('user.store');
}
```

my `UserController.php`:

```
public function store()
{
    return '1';
}
```

but when I do ajax post to

```
/auth/signup
```

It got status code `200` but did not return `1`

And I change route to get wrong for test

```
Redirect::route('user.stor');
```

It got status code `500`

Why it found a valid route but did not execute the function?

Comment: try `dd(1)` instead of `return '1'`

Comment: That would `var_dump()` the RedirectResponse object I'm talking about

Comment: When I tried to do this /auth/signup returned 302 and redirected to `user` as GET request. I think what happen is when you redirect to `user.store` router find corresponding url, which is `/user` and redirect to it as GET request (not as POST).

You may have defined `index()` in `UserController` and you may be getting the output of the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a 200 because

```
return Redirect::route('user.store');
```

returns a RedirectResponse (Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse) object: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html

I can't understand what you're trying to achieve, though: if you want the same action to be called from two different URLs, why not manage it by Routing only? Something like:

```
Route::post('signup', 'UserController@store');
Route::get('store', 'UserController@store);
```